# Proper way to set cookie expire for mac devices

Tags: php, facebook, macos, cookies

I have login system on one of my projects witch use my own login system and facebook login. Issue is Facebook login doesn't seems to be logging out on mac devices.

My code

```
session_start();

if(isset($_COOKIE['checkuserst'])) {
unset($_COOKIE['checkuserst']);
setcookie('checkuserst', '', time() - 3600, '/');
}

unset($_SESSION['username']);

header("Location:index.html");
```

All windows browsers cookies are expiring except for safari and in mac none of the browser cookies are expiring.

Can someone point me the correct way to fix this.

Comment: can you state exactly what you expect to see and what is happening instead?

Comment: @BeetleJuice all windows browsers cookies are expiring except for safari and in mac none of the browser cookies are expiring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rely on cookie expiration in the browser to determine whether a user is logged out (because it's easy for users to fabricate fraudulent cookies).  Store the session expiration in `$_SESSION` or a database. When you receive a request, even if the cookie is present, first check the matching cookie in server storage and make sure it hasn't expired.

This way whatever happens in the browser (eg browser not deleting expired cookies) will not impact your server-side security

Comment: @thank you for the explanation  but my immediate issues is that cookies are not expiring on mac devices. .

Comment: @Jordyn Help me understand why that matters to you. Why is it an issue? How does it affect your site negatively?

Comment: since the cookies are not expiring mac users cannot logout. This is the issue.

Comment: The solution I gave you fixes this issue because it does not rely on the browser respecting cookie expiration; even if the browser doesn't expire the cookie, the logout will work.  You check for expiration in a server variable, not just by looking at the browser's cookies.